Why does updating macOS keep changing my FileVault recovery key?
I have an M1 Mac Mini running macOS 14 Sonoma. Every time I've done a minor system update on it, like from 14.0 to 14.1, or 14.6 to 14.7, and so on, it tells me that there's a new FileVault recovery key. It's happened every single time.
This is not only annoying, but it makes it a lot more likely I'll lose access to this system should I need to use the recovery key, because if I have to keep writing down a new one, it makes it that much more likely I'll accidentally copy it down wrong (because of course you can't copy the key to the clipboard) or lose it somehow.
I'm sure this is not intended behavior. The recovery key is supposed to remain consistent. How can I fix this?

I have observed that as well, although not with every OS update. It is very annoying. This have been reported in various forums, e.g. here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255547095. I have not seen a solution so far.

I can only recommend  to run sudo fdesetup validaterecovery after an update to ensure that you have a valid key.

This article might help.  Apple has a really bad habit of overwriting important files during system updates.  If the key is stored in a file, you can apply a "flag change" to the file that will block Apple's bad habit; how-to reference
